# Calculate mean of every 2nd column in a dataframe

Tags: r, loops, mean

I would like to calculate the row-wise means of every second column in my dataset, meaning:
Average of columns A and B, C and D, E and F. My data look like this:

```
|A|B|C|D|E|F|
|-|-|-|-|-|-|
|0|1|1|1|0|1|
|0|0|1|1|0|0|
|1|1|0|0|0|1|
|0|1|1|1|1|1|
|1|1|1|1|0|1|
```

As a condition I want to include that both values should be greater 0 to compute the mean:

```
data$meanAB <-if_else(A > 0 & B > 0, rowMeans(data[,1:2]), 0)
```

I manage to do this for two columns, but I would like a solution with new columns added to my dataframe with the rowwise means of every 2 columns.
I want to end up with a table like this:

```
|A|B|C|D|E|F|meanAB|meanCD|meanEF|
|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|
|0|1|1|1|0|1|0|1|0|
|0|0|1|1|0|0|0|1|0|
|1|1|0|0|0|1|1|0|0|
|0|1|1|1|1|1|0|1|1|
|1|1|1|1|0|1|1|1|0|
|0|1|1|1|0|1|0|1|0|
|0|0|1|1|0|0|0|1|0|
|1|1|0|0|0|1|1|0|0|
|0|1|1|1|1|1|0|1|1|
|1|1|1|1|0|1|1|1|0|
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R option using `split.default` -

```
cbind(df, sapply(split.default(df, ceiling(seq_along(df)/2)), function(x) {
  ifelse(x[1] > 0 & x[2] > 0, rowMeans(x), 0)
}))

#  A B C D E F 1 2 3
#1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0
#2 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
#3 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
#4 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
#5 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

where column 1 is mean of A & B, column 2 is mean of C & D and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. It uses a `cumsum` trick to get groups of columns, two by two. Then it loops through the split data and computes the row means. Finally, it combines the output with the original input data.

```
cs <- cumsum(seq_len(ncol(data)) %% 2)
res <- lapply(split(as.list(data), cs), \(x){
  rowMeans(as.data.frame(x))
})
res <- do.call(cbind, res)
colnames(res) <- paste0("mean", tapply(names(data), cs, paste, collapse = ""))
cbind(data, res)
#  A B C D E F meanAB meanCD meanEF
#1 0 1 1 1 0 1    0.5      1    0.5
#2 0 0 1 1 0 0    0.0      1    0.0
#3 1 1 0 0 0 1    1.0      0    0.5
#4 0 1 1 1 1 1    0.5      1    1.0
#5 1 1 1 1 0 1    1.0      1    0.5
```

---

### Data in `dput` format

```
data <-
structure(list(A = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), B = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), C = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), D = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), E = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), F = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This also works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse`solution would be. To me this is very short and neat.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attache Paket: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

data <-
  structure(
    list(
      A = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L),
      B = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
      C = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L),
      D = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L),
      E = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L),
      F = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, -5L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )

data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(meanAB = mean(c(A, B)),
         meanCD = mean(c(C, D)),
         meanEF = mean(c(E, F)))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 9
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       A     B     C     D     E     F meanAB meanCD meanEF
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     0     1     1     1     0     1    0.5      1    0.5
#> 2     0     0     1     1     0     0    0        1    0  
#> 3     1     1     0     0     0     1    1        0    0.5
#> 4     0     1     1     1     1     1    0.5      1    1  
#> 5     1     1     1     1     0     1    1        1    0.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Yes sure, but my real dataset is much bigger so this would be a lot of tiping

Comment: Therefore a [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) would be helpful. The way the question is posed, it cannot be guessed that the actual data set has a lot more columns than the given example.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
data[paste0('mean', 1:3)] <-  sapply(split.default(df, as.integer(gl(ncol(df), 
      2, ncol(df)))), function(x) {
     i1 <- rowSums(x > 0) == 2
   replace(rowMeans(x), !i1, 0)})
```